# In SQL, how can I select a row from a table with a particular frequency e.g. frequency = 2 or, frequency = 4?

Tags: sql, frequency-distribution

*I am using the following code* :

```
SELECT d.customer_id, COUNT(*) AS 'frequency' FROM orders d 
GROUP BY d.customer_id
HAVING 'frequency' = 2
;
```

It's showing 'No Result Found'.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: replace having 'frequency' with having count(*)

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo because the OP used single quotes around the column name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT d.customer_id, COUNT(*) AS 'frequency' 
FROM orders d 
GROUP BY d.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```